# Why is MariaDB the default database in my Bitnami LAMP instance and how do I switch it to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, lamp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I recently got a new AWS Bitnami LAMP instance for a new project. However, I noticed the following in the phpMyAdmin portal of my new server:

```
Server type: MariaDB
```

I did some more investigating and determined that this is indeed the database on my server, even though I did not modify the server in any way yet and this never happened when I got my older AWS Bitnami LAMP instance a few months back.

I tried figuring out how to switch to MySQL but came up empty. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: mariadb is a fork of mysql by the original founder of mysql; is there some reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: Oh. I will look into that.

Comment: When Sun Microsystems bought MySQL and commercialized it, some open source purists did not like that and a fork of MySQL called MariaDB was created (by the creator of MySQL, no less and named after his daughter). It's a drop-in replacement for MySQL and you can continue to think you are working with MySQL and nothing changes.

Comment: @RoslanAmir and then Sun (which was fairly pro open source, or MySQL would never have sold itself to them) was bought by Oracle, a company that lives on vendor lock-in and heavy litigation

Comment: @Leo early versions of mariadb were very close to MySQL; since then both have seen a lot of improvements, and not always exactly in the same ways or areas.   If you don't use any features newer than version 5.5, you won't see any differences to speak of, though

Comment: I wish it had Lateral Joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I realized that having MariaDB isn't a problem for me because it is similar to MySQL.

Comment: Apparently AWS Bitnami now uses MariaDB instead of MySQL for its new version. They wouldn't do that if it's not functionally equivalent.